# Bottom margin has no effect on App Bar spacing

Tags: css, alignment, margin

This app bar's bottom margin settings are being ignored while other css rules are displaying correctly:

```
    <AppBar
         className={appBarContainer}
         style={{marginBottom : 100}} // also doesn't work
       >
         <Typography
           variant='h6'
         >{setNavTitle(view)}</Typography>
         <CloseIcon
           onClick={() => setFullViewIsOpen(false)}
           style={{ cursor : 'pointer' }}
         />
       </AppBar>


// App Bar Styles
const defineJss = makeStyles(theme => ({
  appBarContainer : {
    padding : '10px 20px'
    , display : 'flex'
    , flexFlow : 'row nowrap'
    , justifyContent : 'space-between'
    , marginBottom : '100px !important' // removing !important doesn't help
    , '& > *' : {
      border : "2px dashed orange"
    }
  }
}));
```

The `<AppBar />` is from a Material Ui React.js library. Margin top on the next element does work to push everything down but then creates a coupling issue. How can I get `margin-bottom` to work here?

**Working Example**

Here I have the issue shown in a style object: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-heisenberg-jgt9l?fontsize=14

Comment: if you add overflow:auto to the parent element, does it work?

Comment: @TemaniAfif no unfortunately. Also doesn't work if added onto the AppBar

Comment: try to create a runnable example so we can inspect the elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, I have linked a working example of the issue in the top post

Comment: are you sure about the link? I see only 2 titles

Comment: Oops, forgot to save it. I have tested it in a private session and it should work now

Comment: the element is set to position:fixed so margin will have no effect since the element is out of the flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `position="fixed"` (this is the default position of AppBar).

> When you render the app bar position fixed, the dimension of the
>   element doesn't impact the rest of the page. This can cause some part
>   of your content to be invisible, behind the app bar. Here are 3
>   possible solutions:
>
> 1. You can use position="sticky" instead of fixed. ⚠️ sticky is not
>      supported by IE 11.
> 2. You can render a second  component:
>
>    ```
>    function App() {
>      return (
>        <React.Fragment>
>          <AppBar position="fixed">
>            <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
>          </AppBar>
>          <Toolbar />
>        </React.Fragment>
>      );
>    }
>    ```
> 3. You can use theme.mixins.toolbar CSS:
>
>    ```
>    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
>      offset: theme.mixins.toolbar,
>    }))
>
>    function App() {
>      const classes = useStyles();
>      return (
>        <React.Fragment>
>          <AppBar position="fixed">
>            <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
>          </AppBar>
>          <div className={classes.offset} />
>        </React.Fragment>
>      )
>    };
>    ```

In my opinion, the best solution for you is add a separator div, and set it's `marginBottom` to `theme.mixins.toolbar` :

```
function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar
      position="fixed"
               className={classes.appBarContainer}
      >
        Placeholder Text
      </AppBar>
      <div className={classes.appBarSeparator} />
      <p>Exterior Text</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  appBarContainer : {
    offset: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    padding : '10px 20px',
    marginBottom:'200px !important'
    , display : 'flex'
    , flexFlow : 'row nowrap'
    , justifyContent : 'space-between'
    ,  '& > *' : {
      border : "2px dashed orange"
    }
  },
  appBarSeparator: theme.mixins.toolbar
}));
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]